# Finding the value of $x-y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given two equations \begin{align} & x^4+y^4=\dfrac {-7}{9} \\ & x^3-y^3=3. \end{align} From these equations find the value of $(x-y).$
I have just factorize $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=3$. But don't know how to proceed from here. One way to find the values of $x$ and $y$ and then compute possible values of $x-y$. But that is a too long way. I think there is any simple way to find the value of $x-y$. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ allowed to take complex values? If $x$ and $y$ must be real, then $x^4 + y^4 \geq 0$, which is not the case here.

Comment: Let $a = x^2 + y^2$ and $b = xy$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint to get you started:

$$\frac{-7}9= (x^2+y^2)^2-2(xy)^2$$$$3=(x-y)(x^2+y^2+xy)=(x-y)^3+3(xy)(x-y)$$ If we substitute $a=x^2+y^2$ and $b=xy$ and $c=x-y$, we get $$\frac{-7}9=a^2-2b^2$$$$3=c\cdot(a+b)=c^3+3bc$$

Now, you have three equations and three variables. Can you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply equation (2) by $x-y$, giving $(x^4-x^3 y +xy^3 + y^4) = 3(x-y)$.
Next, (1) = -7/9, so

$-x^3 y +xy^3 - 7/9 = 3(x-y)$.
Factorise. 
$xy(-x^2 + y^2) - 7/9 = 3(x-y)$.

$(y-x)(y+x)xy - 7/9 = 3(x-y)$.

$(x-y)(3+(y+x)xy) = - 7/9$

Using your idea, $x^2+xy+y^2 = 3/(x-y) = - 7/3*(3+(y+x)xy)$

Congrats, you now have a quadratic in $x$, or $y$, depending on how you feel.

Next we solve this to get $y$ in terms of $x$.

$3x^2 +3xy + 3y^2 = -21-7xy^2-7x^2y$

Comment: I mean sure, but why not use the symmetry?

Comment: My brain isn't seeing symmetry today unfortunately lol

Comment: In the last equation you have written, $x$ and $y$ are interchangeable.